# System.JSONException: Expected WrapperpaFilterList but found "[line:1, column:2]

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
@AuraEnabled
public static string addRow(string wrapval,integer counterval){
    system.debug('counter value::::'+counterval);
    system.debug('wrapval value ::::::'+wrapval);
    List <WrapperpaFilterList> wList  = (List<WrapperpaFilterList>)JSON.deserialize(wrapval,List<WrapperpaFilterList>.class);

    WrapperpaFilterList objInnerClass = new WrapperpaFilterList();
    Filter_Criteria__c newFilterRecord = new Filter_Criteria__c();        
    objInnerClass.record = newFilterRecord;
    objInnerClass.index = counterval;
    //objInnerClass.index1 = counterval;
    wList.add(objInnerClass);    
    system.debug('------waFilterList---->'+wList); 
    return JSON.serialize(wList);
}
```

---

javascript:

```
       AddRow: function(component, event, helper) {
    alert('add row calling::::');
    var comp1 = component.get("v.wrplst");
    var compJson1 = JSON.stringify(comp1);
    var mapRecords = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < comp1.length; i++) {
        mapRecords.push(comp1[i]);
    }
    var len = mapRecords.length;
    var newlen = len + 1;
    var addAction = component.get("c.addRow");
    addAction.setParams({
        "wrapval": compJson1,
        "counterval": newlen,
    });
    addAction.setCallback(this, function(res) {
        var state = res.getState();
        if (state == 'SUCCESS') {
            component.set("v.wrplst", JSON.parse(res.getReturnValue()));
        } else if (state == 'ERROR') {
            alert('error');
        } else if (state == 'INCOMPLETE') {
            alert('incompltete');
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(addAction);
}
```

---

wrapper class:

```
      public class WrapperpaFilterList {
@AuraEnabled
public Integer index {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public Integer index1 {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public Filter_Criteria__c record {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public string CriteriaMasId{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String ObjectApiNAme{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String FieldName1{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public Criteria_Master__c CriteriaMas{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String SelObjectName {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public string JunctionOperator{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String FieldName{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String Operator{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String LogiaclOperator{get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
public String Value{get;set;}

public WrapperpaFilterList()
{

}
}
```

Comment: what do you see in your debug logs for wrapval in addRow method ?

Comment: Your wrapval method is likely not deserialising properly - try doing it in the exec anon context so you can see what is wrong with the JSON. Also, get the json and run it through an online json syntax checker - eg http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: @vamshi Krishnam, wrapval shows values...Below Line shows error:  List <WrapperpaFilterList> wList  = (List<WrapperpaFilterList>)JSON.deserialize(wrapval,List<WrapperpaFilterList>.class);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you need to do it.

```
Public Class STK_WrapperParentClass{

    @auraEnabled
    Public void STK_WrapperMethod(String wrapperString){
        List <STK_WrapperParentClass.STK_WrapperClass> wList  = (List<STK_WrapperParentClass.STK_WrapperClass>)JSON.deserialize(wrapperString,List<STK_WrapperParentClass.STK_WrapperClass>.class);
    }

    Public Class STK_WrapperClass{
        Public String abc;
    }
}
```

You need to provide the `ParentCLass.ChildWrapperClass` name when deserializing the JSON string.

Comment: I am not sure about this - I think that as long as you are within the parent class you don't need the fully qualified name.

Comment: I agree with your comment, but I had to go through the same when dealing with Aura passed variable.

Comment: I think for wrapper class we have to write separte class correct. I got this error 
   Invalid type: FilterController.WrapperpaFilterList.....                             
 After adding this code:  List <WrapperpaFilterList> wList  = (List<WrapperpaFilterList>)JSON.deserialize(wrapval,List<FilterController.WrapperpaFilterList>.class);

Comment: I have just updated the code, give that a try.

Comment: I have tried  blow code  : List <FilterController.WrapperpaFilterList> wList  = (List<FilterController.WrapperpaFilterList>)JSON.deserialize(wrapval,List<FilterController.WrapperpaFilterList>.class);...It shows error